# PromQL if/else statement for variable mapping a regex

Tags: regex, conditional-statements, grafana, promql

I have a defined variable `service` which can be either `redis-db` or `other-stuff` in my Grafana Dashboard.

I wish to do:

```
if $service =~ ".*redis.*":
  promql-query1
else
  promql-query2
```

What I've achieved, based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64204913/promql-if-else-like-expression), is

```
sum(kube_statefulset_status_replicas_ready{statefulset=~".*redis.*", namespace="$namespace"}) and on() (vector(1) > vector(0)) or on() sum(kube_deployment_status_replicas_available{deployment=~".*$service.*",pod_template_hash="",namespace="$namespace"})
```

It works but I wish to change the `(vector(1) > vector(0))` for `($service =~ ".*redis.*")`, so when variable `redis` is selected, the panel's query is the first one.

Answer (score 1):

Matching an arbitrary string provided as a part of query with a regex is tricky, but possible in promQL.

First of all we need to introduce your string as a label into pseudo metric, as direct operations on the strings are not supported in promQL. This can be done with [function `absent`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#absent): `absent(non_existing_metric{somelabel="$service"})`

Then to check if this introduced label is matching a regex, we can use [function `label_replace`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#label_replace):

```
label_replace(
  absent(non_existing_metric{somelabel="$service"}),
  "flag", "1",
  "somelabel", ".*redis.*")
```

This query will execute a regex match over label `somelabel` in the inroduced pseudometric with regex `.*redis.*`, and if it matches, new label `flag` with value `1` will be added.

And finally, to check if the label `flag` was actually added, you can use `and on(flag)` with new pseudometric:

```
label_replace(
  absent(non_existing_metric{somelabel="$service"}),
  "flag", "1",
  "somelabel", ".*redis.*")
 and on(flag) absent(non_existing_metric{flag="1"})
```

This query will return result only if variable `$service` matched provided regex.

Then based on principles provided in [last part of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78088338/21363224), your final query might be

```
(
  sum(kube_statefulset_status_replicas_ready{statefulset=~".*redis.*", namespace="$namespace"})
  and on() (
    label_replace(
      absent(non_existing_metric{somelabel="$service"}),
      "flag", "1",
      "somelabel", ".*redis.*")
    and on(flag) absent(non_existing_metric{flag="1"})
  )
) or on() (
  sum(kube_deployment_status_replicas_available{deployment=~".*$service.*",pod_template_hash="",namespace="$namespace"})
  unless on() (
    label_replace(
      absent(non_existing_metric{somelabel="$service"}),
      "flag", "1",
      "somelabel", ".*redis.*")
    and on(flag) absent(non_existing_metric{flag="1"})
  )
)
```

Or compacted a bit

```
(
  sum(kube_statefulset_status_replicas_ready{statefulset=~".*redis.*", namespace="$namespace"})
  and on() (
    label_replace(absent(_{_="$service"}), "f", "1", "_", ".*redis.*")
    and on(flag) absent(_{f="1"})
  )
) or on() (
  sum(kube_deployment_status_replicas_available{deployment=~".*$service.*",pod_template_hash="",namespace="$namespace"})
  unless on() (
    label_replace(absent(_{_="$service"}), "f", "1", "_", ".*redis.*")
    and on(flag) absent(_{f="1"})
  )
)
```